# How to get a bearer token to access an API from an MVC application

Tags: identityserver3

My user flow is as follows...

1. User requests a protected resource.
2. User redirected to authentication provider (e.g. Google)
3. User redirect back to ASP.Net MVC application which uses cookie authentication.

This works great, and following the MVC sample application from the IdentityServer samples I can see a list of claims for my user.

So the main page of my application is rendered using an MVC view, I have other resources which are authorised via resource authorisation and this works great.

The next part of my application is an API. Let's say it's `api.domain.com/stockquote`

This should only be useable by authorised users of my application and not publically available.

I have successfully made an Angular JS application with Identity Server and understand that when the token is returned I am able to get the value of `/id_token` from the URI, store it in localstorage and then use it to form an authorisation header for the API e.g. `Authorization=Bearer {token}`  . Again works nicely.

However, now I am authenticated into my MVC application how do I get this token and put it into local storage so that I can create a header for my API calls?

- Can I extract it from the cookie somehow?
- Is it a good idea to output it in the HTML stream so that JS can pick it up and put into localstorage (guessing now).
- Can I use the token endpoint to somehow get this token?

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this might be to change the way you authenticate. Instead of handling the callback in MVC on the server side, handle it in JavaScript. Then the token is available for you to store in local storage. This might not be possible if you are making requests on the server side that uses the token as well.

Comment: Interesting, if I set the MVC app. to cookie authentication but handle the callback in JS would that work? That is would the MVC app. get a cookie but I also have the token in the query string for local storage?

Comment: The postback is going to a page that can have JavaScript on it. So you can handle the request on both the server side and the JavaScript side if you want.